# Why first code output is false and true in second code?

Tags: c

Code 1

---

```
#include<stdio.h>    

int main(){
const char st1[]={"Hello"};
const char st2[]={"Hello"};

if(st1==st2){
  printf("True");
}
else{
  printf("False");
}
return 0;
}
```

Code 2

---

```
int main(){
const char *st1="Hello";
const char *st2="Hello";

if(st1==st2){
    printf("True");
}
else{
    printf("False");
}
return 0;
}
```

Now in first code char array become const. 
In the first code I got False as optput. 
And in second code its true. 
Thank in advance

Comment: You compare pointers, not content. Second can also return false Btw.

Comment: But why first one is false

Comment: Second returns true is because this compile is clever to figure out these 2 strings are the same.

Comment: @manni66 Don't agree. `stdio.h` is much more flexible in formatting.

Comment: @liliscent yes, it's so flexible that you can easily shoot yourself into the foot.

Comment: Really, now it's a C question?

Comment: @manni66: It would appear that way. It's ruined my answer on a technical point.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Totally wrong answer for both C and C++. Pls, vote for delete.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. In the first snippet, `st1` and `st2` are not pointers, they are arrays. In the second one, they are pointers to `char`, not pointers to arrays. And things they point to most probably are not on the heap.

Comment: C does not have a stack. Please provide a reference to the standard stating otherwise. And HolyBlackCat is right, arrays are not pointers nor vice-vera.

Comment: And @Olaf is rarely wrong (I've never known them to be) either. This answer is defective.

Answer (score 1):

`==` does **not** compare the string contents.

In the first snippet `st1` are `st2` `char[6]` types with automatic storage duration, and you are allowed to modify the string contents. When using `==` these types *decay* to `char*`. Their addresses must be different, so `==` will yield `false`.

In the second snippet, the string literals are *read only*, in C they are still formally `char[6]` (cf. C++ where they are `const char[6]` types) although the behaviour on attempting to modify the contents is *undefined*. Using `const char*` types for them is perfectly acceptable and reasonable. Because the contents are read only, the compiler *might* use the same string and so `st1` and `st2` *might* point to the same location in memory. In your case, that is happening, and the result of `==` is `true`.

Answer (score -1):

The second is true because you are using an optimizing compiler. Since `str1` and `str2` are pointers, it makes them point to the same string, thus saving a little memory.